# Unusual output of preg_replace_callback() with var_dump

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~', function ($match) {
    //return strtoupper($match[1]);
        var_dump($match);
    }, 'hello-world');
?>
```

This is a modification on the Example #1 on http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php . The var_dump within the anonymous function outputs this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "-w" [1]=> string(1) "w" } helloorld
```

Anybody has an idea what may be going on?

Thanks.

Comment: There's __nothing__ going wrong. Instead, you should explain what you expect.

Comment: Why the "helloorld" is out of the array and why is it modified, meaning not "helloworld", since we are looking for [a-z].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This should explain the regex part.](https://regex101.com/r/kJ0ScQ/1)
Now to the `echo` part where `-w` is missing: as you can see, [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) does operations on `$match`. Since `$match[0]` is your matched string, `preg_replace_callback` expects a replacement as return value in the anonymous function. You have skipped that part in your example, thus, the replacement is empty.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~', function ($match) {
    //return strtoupper($match[1]);
    var_dump($match);
}, 'hello-world');
```

You're trying to replace `-([a-z])` (`-w` matches it) with **nothing**, as your callback **returns** nothing.

So, replacing `-w` with nothing (which is casted to empty string) in string `hello-world` gives you `helloorld`.

Comment: Thanks for the info.